# Block certain filetypes from being copied onto local machine from a USB

Tags: c#, .net, security, usb

The title sounds a little confusing so let me clarify.

I want to be able to stop (for example a .exe file) from being imported onto the machine the USB drive is plugged into.

Is there a way to stop a list of file extensions coming from a USB drive?

What I am shooting for...

My application will be running and whenever one puts a USB drive in and drags a .exe file to the desktop, I want my application to check its extension type and delete the file or block it from even coming onto the computer.

Is this even possible? If so, how? Maybe this can be done better with a different language?

Mainly, I would like to block .exe, .msi, .zip, and a few others.

Comment: This doesn't sound like a good solution to the problem.  Can't the user change the extension of a file to something that isn't blocked to get around this?

Comment: Perhaps, but whenever they change the file extension back to .exe after importing the file the application will handle the file. I dont want to completely disable the USB because some files will have to come off the USB drive.

The machine is setup to where files can only be placed onto the desktop, all other folders/files are hidden. In this case, if I know how to detect a file type and handle it, I will be able to figure out that walk around about changing the extension.

Comment: Mind posting the solution so that others can find it?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to get by with the FileSystemWatcher since you're only watching the desktop and subfolders.